# AWS free tier account lightsail instance creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to create an aws lightsail instance. I just opened my free account a couple weeks back. I login, go to [lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/instances) and press create, select my configurations, select the $5 plan which says free for the first month, and then I get this message:

> Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 0. If you're new to Lightsail, please try again later. If the issue persists, please contact Customer Support .
>   ResourceLimitExceeded

Why is this happening? I have never used lightsail before.

Comment: If this question does not belong here, let me know and I will just delete it.

Comment: Check whether your AWS account is having a verified credit card?

Comment: @Ashan Yes it is

Comment: Side-note: It's not a free account. It's a normal account but some services have a free usage tier for the first 12 months. As to the problem... have you tried it in a different region, just to see if it reports the same issue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes. I have tried it in many regions and configurations. Same happens to me in EC2 as well.

Comment: "...Same happens to me in EC2 as well..." Yep, that is an account config error. Raise a ticket with the support team.

Answer (score 7):

I can't explain why the limit was set to zero, but you can request an increase in the limit from AWS Support.

From [Manage AWS Service Limits](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-service-limits/):

> You can request most service limit increases through the [AWS Support Center](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/) by choosing **Create Case** and selecting **Service Limit Increase**.

Amazon LightSail is offered as an option.

Comment: we can't request anything without subscribing to a $29 plan. What is the point the of a free trial that we need to pay for support just to be able to start the free trial? Makes no sense

Comment: @Burgos You could try contacting Customer Service (which is different to Customer Support). They handle Account-related queries. See: https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while developing for a client.
Contacted support and was advised we verify the account.

After phone verification, ERROR CLEARED.