# Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

In a normal account (no AWS Free Tier), when attempting to create more than two Lightsail instances in the same region I get

> CreateInstances [eu-west-2]
>
> Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 2.
> If you're new to Lightsail, please try again later. If the issue
> persists, please contact [Customer Support](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home).

[image: Amazon Lightsail instances limit]

Thing is, in the [Service Quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lightsail.html#limits_lightsail) page can read that the Number of instances per Region is 20.

[image: Amazon Lightsail service quotas]

Can see that [I can request an increase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49593640/5675325) in this limit and could create the instance in a different location - I've tested and that's allowed - but want all services/products in the same region so that's not an option for me).

[image: Three instances but limit of two per region]

Shouldn't I be allowed 20 per region? What am I missing here?

As stated in the error message, considering I'm new to Lightsail (less than one month of usage), will "try again later" and see if that solves.

Comment: Is your AWS account rather new (eg only 1-2 days old)? There are some mysterious processes that happen on new accounts that normally resolve after a couple of days (eg checking your credit card number).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no, it's older than 4 years. Yet the usage of Lightsail isn't longer than 2 weeks.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You should [contact AWS Customer Service](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) (which is different to AWS Support). They take care of quota limits and billing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i'll wait today and test to create a new one tomorrow (following through what the error message says). If that still doesn't solve, will write them. Thank you!

Comment: Tested now again and the same problem showed up. Will test again tomorrow and if it persists will contact support.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the problem remains. From that contact page, under which category does this apply to? Technical support?

Comment: Choose "Billing/Account Support" -- they handle account limits.

Comment: Feel free to write that as an answer @JohnRotenstein, I'll then edit it to include more info.

Comment: same issue here. 2 instances in Paris. account is 1 month old. gives that error when try to create another instance. considering 2 years have passed from this post, this is probably not a technical error, this is marketing. they want people for whatever reason to contact support or god knows what

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following John Rotenstein's suggestion, I went to the [AWS's Contact Page](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) and under Billing/Account Support raised in 2020-10-03 a case with the following text

```
Hi AWS support team

In a normal account (no AWS Free Tier), when attempting to create more than two Lightsail instances in the same region I get

> "CreateInstances [eu-west-2]
> Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 2. If you're new to Lightsail, please try again later. If the issue persists, please contact Customer Support."

Thing is, in the Service Quotas page can read that the Number of instances per Region is 20. Shouldn't I be allowed 20 per region? What am I missing here?

As stated in the error message, considering I'm new to Lightsail (less than one month of usage), I "tried again" after 8 hours and then after 21 hours but the problem remained and hence the question.

Attentively
Tiago Peres
```

[image: Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 2]

and one day after received a response including

```
Thank you for reaching us regarding this matter, and we apologize for any inconvenience. In order to reach a resolution to this matter, I have engaged our Service Team to dive deep into this request.

Rest assured, I have shared the necessary details to make sure that the investigation is completed as effectively as possible, if there's any information missing from your end I will be reaching you directly.

Since I understand how important this is for you, I will be requesting periodical updates in order to ensure a prompt resolution. Once we have received information, we will be reaching back to you.
```

The problem now solved. The limit of LightSail instances has been updated successfully to 20 on the EU (London) region.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I submitted the support ticket asking for more instances. After a few NEXT buttons, the support guy over the chat told me:
"please check again".
He said there is a validation process for your account, after submitting the request for more instances. It takes a few minutes.
I just tried the same again, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to get through this error.

First Way:

1. Go to this link - https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home.
2. Raise an increased request for an increasing number of instances [image]

Second Way:

Create new instances in other regions!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).